# How can I continue my Nazjatar main quests?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In the past, I was doing the Nazjatar quests.

Yesterday, I re-open WoW but I wasn't able to find the Nazjatar quest.
I don't know the quests that I've already realized in the Nazjatar island so I can't find my current quest.

In the island, I've just 1 fly and I don't find a PNJ that give quest.
Someone can point me?

Comment: Pretty hard to do that without any hints.. you obviously have unlocked the portal, otherwise there would be no FP. Does the campfire near the FP (for alliance; not sure if it's the same for horde) give you a repeatable/daily quest to choose an ally? Otherwise you haven't unlocked the main line, yet. Do you have any open Nazjatar quests in your log?

Comment: I don't know how can I see if I've active Nazjatar quests. Previously, I've unlocked the island but I don't know what was my current quest.

Comment: Do you have an active War Campaign quest? You may need to complete the Baine scenario in order to unlock Nazjatar dailies.

Comment: @Cadence yes the War Campaign is activated, but when I'm on the Nazjatar island, I didn't find any quest...

Comment: Does a way exists to see the quests already done yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have not completed the story in Nazjatar and you have abandoned the quest the next story quest will show up on the map with an Yellow exclamation sign.

An exception to this is the part where Magni asks for your help, you need to do the following quests for him and might be on one of them:

- [Essential Empowerment](https://www.wowhead.com/quest=55851/essential-empowerment)
- [MOTHER Knows Best](https://www.wowhead.com/quest=55533/mother-knows-best)
- [A Disturbance Beneath the Earth](https://www.wowhead.com/quest=55374/a-disturbance-beneath-the-earth)
- [Take My Hand](https://www.wowhead.com/quest=55400/take-my-hand)
- [Calming the Spine](https://www.wowhead.com/quest=55407/calming-the-spine)
- [Dominating the Indomitable](https://www.wowhead.com/quest=55425/dominating-the-indomitable)
- [A Friendly Face](https://www.wowhead.com/quest=55497/a-friendly-face)
- [The HeartForge](https://www.wowhead.com/quest=55618/the-heart-forge)
- [Harnessing the Power](https://www.wowhead.com/quest=57010/harnessing-the-power)
- [Back Out to Sea](https://www.wowhead.com/quest=56162/back-out-to-sea) / [Back Out to Sea](https://www.wowhead.com/quest=56161/back-out-to-sea)

Answer (score 0):

*World of Warcraft* does not currently have the ability to show completed quests.

This means you're stuck looking around for the correct NPC (or PNJ for French and Spanish speakers).
If you don't care much for spoilers it might be an idea to just look up an online guide for Nazjatar (e.g. [this one](https://www.wowhead.com/guides/comprehensive-nazjatar-guide#nazjatar-storyline-welcome-to-nazjatar)) and checking each quest-starting NPC in quest-line order.

With more details we might be able to help you narrow it down more, but this should already work.